# Centos LInux shell script execute 2 minutes after the server has been rebooted

Tags: linux, centos, bash, scripting

I would like to have a simple shell script that will be executed 2 min after my server came up 
after reboot.

I just want to have a service restarted.
can anyone advice?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just fix the problem that requires the service to be restarted in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an **at** job on system boot, either from a new init script or from **/etc/rc.local**.

```
echo "command to run etc" | at `date --date='2 minutes' +%H:%M`
```

Comment: or just echo "command to run etc" | at now + 2 minutes